# problem in subreport

Tags: vb.net

suppose i have 2 schema,i.e. fy0910 and fy1011.so when i see the report in schema fy0910 or in fy1011 i have to change every time the schema reference for the subreport,but when i see the report in the specific schema after setting the schema reference then there is no problem in subreport but when i go to another schema then again i have to change the schema reference for sub report.For your kind information there is absolutely no problem in main report.so plz give solution to me i will be thankful to u.

Answer (score 0):

What I have done with my reports is to generate a generic result table schema, such as FYDetails instead of your FY0910 and FY1011.  Your query to the database can be exactly the same, but with your obvious date limit parameters that only show respective fiscal year.  Then, add the FYDetails schema to your report as the binding basis and do a global search / replace on your report file from the fy0910 to FYDetails and save.

Then, whenever you run your queries, just ensure you change the data table result name and your good to go.  I almost never hard-code reports to a specific table name that are a direct result of a specific filtered set.

HTH